# Delegates conversion

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have two delegates with same signature:

```
public delegate void A();
public delegate void B();
```

and I have some generic method which calls the delegate:

```
public void Do<TDelegate>(TDelegate delegateToCall) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    if (typeof(TDelegate) == typeof(A)
    {
        // cast to A and call
    }
    else 
    {
        // cast to B and call
    } 
}
```

The problem is explicit casting - if I want to cast `delegateToCall` to delegate `A`

```
var castedToA = (A)delegateToCall; // error
```

I get compile-time error:

> Cannot cast expression of type 'TDelegate' to type 'A'

So I found answer which suggests to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` to create new delegate of needed type:

```
var castedToA = (A)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(A), delegateToCall.Target, delegateToCall.Method);
```

This works fine (I also need to check invocation list and combine if multiple items are there) but I wonder why the explicit casting does not work with delegates?

Also the casting is possible when casting to `object` before (and it looks simpler):

```
var castedToA = (A)(object)delegateToCall; // no error and works with MulticastDelegate
```

Are there any pitfalls when using second option (casting to `object` and then to required delegate) over first one (`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`)?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** The code is simplified so please do not ask about the purpose of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why the explicit casting does not work with delegates?

It's not about delegates. It's about generics.

You'd have the same thing with any other type, e.g. `string`:

```cs
public static void MaybeCast<T>(T value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        string x = (string) value;
    }
}
```

The C# rules of conversions don't allow this - while it would be convenient for them to do so, it gets tricky in some cases.

Fortunately, you can cast to `object` and then to the specific type:

```cs
public static void MaybeCast<T>(T value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        string x = (string) (object) value;
    }
}
```

... or in your case:

```cs
public void Do<TDelegate>(TDelegate delegateToCall) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    if (typeof(TDelegate) == typeof(A)
    {
        A actualDelegate = (A) (object) delegateToCall;
    }
    else 
    {
        B actualDelegate = (B) (object) delegateToCall;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I see I can also use `(delegateToCall as A)()` to call the delegate and it also casts to correct type (not `null`).